# Logic App : Finding element in Json Object array (like XPath fr XML)

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

In my logic app, I have a JSON object (parsed from an API response) and it contains an object array.

How can I find a specific element based on attribute values... Example below where I want to find the (first) active one

```
{
    "MyList" : [
        {
            "Descrip" : "This is the first item",
            "IsActive" : "N"
        },
        {
            "Descrip" : "This is the second item",
            "IsActive" : "N"
        },
        {
            "Descrip" : "This is the third item",
            "IsActive" : "Y"
        }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well... The answer is in plain sight ... There's a **FILTER ARRAY** action, which works on a JSON Object (from PARSE JSON action).. couple this with an `@first()` expression will give the desired outcome.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the *Parse JSON* Task to parse your JSON and a *Condition*  to filter for the `IsActive` attribute:

Use the following **Schema** to parse the JSON:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "MyList": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "Descrip": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "IsActive": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        },
        "required": [
          "Descrip",
          "IsActive"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here how it looks like (I included the sample data you provided to test it):
[image]

Then you can add the **Condition**:

[image]

And perform whatever action you want within the *If true*  section.

Comment: I guess that'll work ... I'll give it a try ... thanks